# What method / How to replace two consecutive same characters with the single character has different condition

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication5

{
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            Console.WriteLine("INPUT: ");
            String input = Console.ReadLine();
            int index = 0;

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input);
            builder.Replace("a", "aa");

            builder.Replace("bb", "b");

            builder.Replace("c", "");
            Console.WriteLine("OUTPUT: " + builder);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

When I input two consecutive letter c's it must add cc to the output. and if I input a single c it must skip it or remove it. My problem is the two consecutive c's is being removed because of 
builder.Replace("c", "");   what method should I use?

sample  input : abaabbcbaccb

output must be : aabaaaabbaaccb

Comment: `builder.Replace("b", "b")` and `builder.Replace("cc", "cc")` are **pointless**

Comment: If this is a homework, then please provide full task description as you have it. Your current description is not clear

Comment: Are you required to use `StringBuilder.Replace`?

Comment: Sounds like a good place to use Regex.

Comment: What happens with three consecutive `c`'s? Or 4?

Comment: if 3 c's 2 will display and 1 will be deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
builder.Replace("a", "aa");
builder.Replace("b", "b");
builder.Replace("bb", "b");
builder.Replace("cc", "~");
builder.Replace("c", "");
builder.Replace("~", "cc");
```

Comment: It's a temporary char. You change cc's to ~ and then change them back to cc's. Beauty of simplicity :)

Comment: just any character for replace which will not used in your input string

Comment: @AmitTiwari you should add an explanation about it.don't just write code

Comment: @Selman22 I don't think that 3-line algorhitms need any explanation. Please do not downvote the only useful answer here.

Comment: @Tarec I didn't downvote.If OP needs to ask about it that means he need an explanation right?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not required to use `StringBuilder.Replace`, how about a `Regex`:

```
[^c](c)[^c]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YqBOgAOLTIqQOZp_)

You could use that like this:

```
var s = Regex.Replace(input, "[^c](c)[^c]", "");
```

Comment: The c may be at the beginning or end of string.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate all single c's:

```
srt = Regex.Replace(str, "(?<=[^c]|^)c(?=[^c]|$)", match => "");
```

Comment: @Tarec OP wants single c's to be removed ccc is not a single c.

Comment: Yes, but he explained that in comment above, that every pair of cc's should be kept and the single c's should be omited when left.